# Connecting Google Sheets To MySQL Database using Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, mysql-connector

So I am new to google apps script and relatively experienced with MySQL.
I was using google apps script to try and make a connection to the databses using Jdbc

```
function OpenConnection() {
    var URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + schema;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(URL, username, password);
    Logger.log(conn)
    conn.close();
}
```

this is the code with the server hostname being localhost and port being the default 3306

[this is the error message which comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3X28.png) when I run it, it is an "unknown error has occured, please try again later".
I originally thought it was the connection url but I have looked throught the MySQL documentation and it seemed to be right so I have no idea what it is now?

Any help would Appreciated

Comment: Did you always receive this error message while trying to establish the connection? Since this may have been a temporary error, are you still receiving the error message now?

Comment: Yes, This error message has always been like that and the server is definitely running. I Just checked and it is still the same error message

Comment: Did you add the IP addresses to the allow-list? According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#other_databases) `In order to create a database connection using the JDBC service you must allow-list certain IP ranges in your database settings to allow Apps Script to access it.`

Comment: yes, using the % wildcard allows for any IP to go through a specific user profile, I know it's not great but it takes much less time than putting in every IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try using the Rhino runtime

The JDBC connector is not working as expected and there is a public issue open on this:

> #### [Problems with V8 runtime and JDBC](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841)

The current best workaround for issues with this is to downgrade the runtime. This will mean that you can't use the latest JavaScript syntax in your code.

[image]

[image]